# Regex to not allow duplicate wild cards

Tags: regex, regex-group

I want to make regex which can pass the following cases:

```
02:12
10:23
00.23
0.23
.02
:88
```

Here is what i have tried:  `^([0-9:. ])*[.: ]+$`

But it allows duplicate" :, ., (space)", and also I'm not able to limit to 1-2 digits on both sides of wildcards. Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern you tried only matches digits on the left side and matching the duplicates is due to the quantifiers.

If you want to allow 1 or 2 digits on both sides and make the digits on the left optional:

```
^[0-9]{0,2}[.:][0-9]{1,2}$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[0-9]{0,2}` Match 0, 1 or 2 times a digit 0-9
- `[.:]` Match either `.` or `:`
- `[0-9]{1,2}` Match 1 or 2 times a digit 0-9
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fPguhv/1)